# How does if __name__ == '__main__': takes file path

Tags: python, program-entry-point, python-module, argv, sys

I have written a driver code to take file path from user and use that file path in my functions. Driver code is as below;

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: %s input_file" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit()

    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    connection, color, numOf_Nodes,links = read_problem(file_path)

    print(links)
    graph_coloring(connection, color, 0, numOf_Nodes)
```

But when I run this code I got following error:

```
Usage: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py input_file
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
```

Shouldn't it ask for a file path from user? I am new to use a driver code therefore I might skip to write  some parts for the driver code to work.

Any help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: You have to pass the input file name on the command line.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you! I have corrected it

Comment: What is the name of this file? How are you running this code? Are you running it at the command line or in an IDE like Python IDLE or in Jupyter Notebook or something else?

Comment: My only suggestion is to do what the error message says: "An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback." I don't know exactly what this means, though, and I'm not familiar ipython.

Answer (score 0):

The code is expecting that the user pass a file path on the command line.  You want to execute your code with something like this:

```
python ipykernel_launcher.py /path/to/input/file
```

Upon execution of your code, the variable `file_path` will get a value of `/path/to/input/file`.

The variable `sys.argv` contains the script name in the first position, followed by each of the arguments passed to the script on the command line.  That's why `2` is the appropriate expectation here...the first value in the array is the script name.  The second value is the file path argument to the program.

Comment: @SteveActually I will submit this code file (.py file) with a submit.pyc file via command prompt. However it could not submit to the system. Normally it should without giving the file path. Therefore I suspected that maybe I did sth wrong in the driver code part.

Comment: @svn_21 What are you submitting the code file to exactly? It sounds like we need more details to help you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There is a website created to take our submissions via submit.pyc file. I have my own user name and password. I use this command from cmd:  python submit.cpython-38.pyc 1 -u username -p password. In the working directory I have my data file, .py file and manifest.txt. So, normally by only above command it should take file and manifest and submit to the submission website

Comment: @svn_21 So is this for a university class assignment? It sounds like you need to ask your instructor about how to do what you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes it is, and I asked to my instructor, but she said that I should check my code :/ I checked my functions they are all working, so I suspected that I did sth wrong for the driver code part :/

Comment: @svn_21 Yes, when code doesn't do what you want, it usually means there's something wrong with it, but there isn't enough information in your question for us to help you.